# Inverse of the matrix with several indices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

Suppose I have a square matrix $A_{mn}$ where $m=(i,j)$ and $n=(k,l)$. For example, if $i,j,k,l=1..N$ the matrix is $N^2\times N^2$. For simplicity, let me generate it by

```
n = 3;
A = RandomReal[1, {n, n, n, n}];
```

I want to find an inverse of this matrix: $A^{-1}_{(i,j)(k,l)}$. I understand how to it by introducing another square matrix  $B=A_{mn}$ and inverting it:

```
B = ConstantArray[0, {n^2, n^2}];
Do[
 B[[i + n ( j - 1)]][[k + n ( l - 1)]] = A[[i]][[j]][[k]][[l]];
 , {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}
 ]
Bi = Inverse[B];
Ai = Table[
   Bi[[i + n ( j - 1)]][[k + n ( l - 1)]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 
    1, n}, {l, 1, n}];
```

I believe there should be a better way of doing it(maybe using some tensor commands)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B = ArrayFlatten[Transpose[A, {3, 1, 4, 2}]];
Ai = Transpose[ArrayReshape[Inverse[B], {n, n, n, n}], {2, 1, 4, 3}];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is there an easy way to understand why you transpose these layers?

Comment: Well, I just do it to get the ordering right. Please don't ask to figure out the right permutation! I just tried a couple of permutations until it worked! ;)